# Handle ImageView pictures in Android

Tags: android, imageview, image

i have a question about pictures in an ImageView in Android.

My problem is, that the pic i wanna show in my ImageView seems too big for my smartphone screen. Therefore it is not on the place i set in the xml...

Here is a pic that you know what i mean: http://www10.pic-upload.de/31.10.12/iuebxzkvr3e.png
The grey area is my Banner which should be located on top of my activity... 
If i scale the pic, it should work (the smaller, the higher till it fits), but i think other smartphones with a different resolution should have the same problem again with my app..

Here is my XML:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/ivBanner"
               android:src="@drawable/banner"/>
```

Nothing special.

thanks in advance

Comment: android:scaleType http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: You can pre scale the image for major categories `ldpi`,`mdpi`,`hdpi`,`xhdpi`  using a decent image editor on PC (since android scaling is not _that much_ quality centric, and on a PC image editor you can run anti-alising filters, plus sharpen the low-res parts). To get the idea about dpi to pixels ratios you will need, use [this tool](http://labs.skinkers.com/content/android_dp_px_calculator/).

Comment: So... i have to scale the banner to 360px width, that it fits on my galaxy nexus. How can that be? thought it's 480px.. :/ i dont get it. :D help is appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout you should set its height and width to absolute dp values:

Here is a px to dp converter:

http://labs.skinkers.com/content/android_dp_px_calculator/

That solved the problem for me, for every screen size you need a different values(hdpi/xhdpi).

Answer (score 0):

you can set scaleType for ImageView to fitXY, or centerCrop

```
android:scaleType = "fitXY"
```